# Modifying Omnibox suggestion priority in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I am writing a Google Chrome extension that will use the keyword `\\` as an Omnibox trigger. This is working well, and I am achieving most of the desired result, except that the priority of the Omnibox always suggests `file://` before suggesting my app.

I have read about ways to change priorities of Omnibox suggestions within my browser (manually selecting with keyboard, etc.). But is there anyway change suggestion order within the extension code, such that if the extension were deployed on any browser, `\\` would trigger my extension before it suggested `file://`?

Any help or push in the right direction would be welcome.